# Firebase Angular app not connecting h NodeJS app on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, firebase

I have deployed a node server on Heroku and client Angular app on Firebase, but I am facing this problem. Please help me to get out of this.

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://newone-2754f.firebaseapp.com/#/login' 
 was   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest 
 endpoint    'http://localhost:8080/authenticate'. 
 This request has been blocked; the content   must be served over HTTPS.
  (anonymous) @ angular.js:12011
  sendReq @ angular.js:11776
  serverRequest @ angular.js:11571
  processQueue @ angular.js:16383
 (anonymous) @ angular.js:16399
  $eval @ angular.js:17682
  $digest @ angular.js:17495 
  $apply @ angular.js:17790
  (anonymous) @ angular.js:25890
defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3497
eventHandler @ angular.js:3485
angular.js:12011 XMLHttpRequest cannot 
load    http://localhost:8080/authenticate. Failed to start loading.
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12011
sendReq @ angular.js:11776
serverRequest @ angular.js:11571
processQueue @ angular.js:16383
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16399
 $eval @ angular.js:17682
 $digest @ angular.js:17495
   $apply @ angular.js:17790
(anonymous) @ angular.js:25890
defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3497
eventHandler @ angular.js:3485
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What you present here provides nobody with any idea of how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you deployed your code, it seems that the http request endpoints(the nodejs api endpoints) remained the local one. Correct the endpoints

```
 was   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest 
 endpoint    'http://localhost:8080/authenticate'. 
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // Add heroku app url there
 This request has been blocked; the content   must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: how to do that...i am beginner please help me

Comment: Is this problem from node js or angular js

Comment: Not sure if it's external service or internal API endpoint, if it's in your current server domain, make the request only to `/authenticate` endpoint.

Comment: This seems to be client side issue(Angular).

Comment: actually when i run client server on my machine then there is no error. but when i deployed to firebase and then i am facing problem.  https://newone-2754f.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: this the link of my deployed app

Comment: if you dnt mind please hit this with login id : test and password: test

Comment: then check  the console of you browser

Comment: what should be the expected output, show the code that causes the problem. I am not sure are you trying to handle the authentication through your own system or use the Firebase auth? From your client side code it's seems to use your auth implementation `$http.post('https://fathomless-ocean-26476.herokuapp.com/authenticate/', user)`. also the post url would be better if it's relative `$http.post('/authenticate/', user)`